# c# - App.config placing and accessing

Tags: c#, app-config, config

I created a c#.net application which uses a App.Config.
While debugging everything works fine of course.
I can access the file to read and write.

But when i created a installer for my application the writing part didn't work anymore.

This was because of the fact that the application was installed in program files. and you can't write to de program files folder...

I kinda thought of a solution to place the app.config in de AppData Folder but I cant get it to work.

What i want to know is how to instruct my installer to place a file in the correct location and how to create the correct function to write it it on that location.

Here is what i had so far:

```
 public static void WriteValue(string key, string value)
 {
    string configPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                                         Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + 
                        "\\Application\\app.config";

    ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(configPath);

    // Open App.Config of executable
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, 
                                                                           ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Add an Application Setting.
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
    // Save the configuration file.
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    // Force a reload of a changed section.
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Thank you guys in Advance

Comment: How are you installing the application? The basic idea is to give proper access rights to the file (ie app.config) during installation.

Comment: app config files should remain in the installed location and not in in application data.

Comment: It seems like access issue, you need to grant the write access to the app.config file.

Comment: Hi guys, the problem is that in windows vista and 7 you cant write to the program files directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `App.config` is the name used during the development process and during debugging the VS reads it just fine.

But when you run your executable `YourProgram.exe` outside the studio, it searches for file named `YourProgram.exe.config`

Hope it helps.